# how to make sqlite column aliases numeric or computed

Tags: sql, sqlite

i'm trying with sqlite to make code like this working:

```
select 
    data1 as 1
    data2 as 'hello' + 'hi     [or 'hello' || 'hi']
    data3 as 6 * 3
from 
    table
```

but every effort was vain...
i tried with the || concatenation or with the +
i tried with something like

```
...AS select 6 * 3
```

but it seems like no operation is admitted in column aliases!
how can i set poperly the column alias of a select?

thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an expression as column name is not possible in sqlite. [Here](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html) is the full allowed syntax of sqlite. The [*column-alias*](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#result-column) after *as* doesn't accept expression:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A column alias is an identifier like a table name or column name.

To use an arbitrary string, you have to quote it, like with other identifiers:

```
SELECT 42 AS "42 is the answer!!!"
```

You cannot do computations on identifiers.